# Move Linux system to new SSD alongside with Windows

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, file-transfer

I've got a new PC with a new SSD #2. They preinstalled the Windows on it and I'm cool with it.

However, I have a Linux system on my old SSD #1 and I want to keep that data. The problem is I've only managed to connect my SSD #1 to new PC with the external source so *I decided to move that system from SSD #1 to SSD #2 alongside Windows.* With Sata SSD - USB to be precise.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to do that to make

1. Both OS functional
2. SSD #1 size is 220 gb, while on SSD #2 I want to dedicate 500 gb and extend partition sizes.
3. How to preserve my SSD #1 Linux partitions (grub, home, system)
4. Make grub work to run 2 systems

How SSD #1 looks now in GPARTED
[image]

How SSD #2 looks in GPARTED. I already tried to allocated 500 gb.
[image]

**Please help me to move my old Linux system from SSD #1 to the new SSD #2 with Windows alongside already.**

My guess is to create partition by partition and copy over the data. However, I suspect some pitfalls I don't encounter. For example how to deal with the boot partition? And doesn't it mess up the structure smh. And of course, the challenge is to preserve systems data. That complicates a task.

Comment: If you want to dual boot this PC, then the safest approach is perform two steps: (1) install Linux using a LiveCD/DVD of the same distro version as "*SSD #1*". This is the fool-proof method of getting this crucial boot setup correctly. (2) Copy over user files from "*SSD #1*" to the new installation.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment yet and I am not an expert either, but I will suggest some points based on what I have done until now (FYI, I have completely corrupted my Windows boot record two time before, when I was fixing my linux boot, and fixed it successfully )

I assume you have used gparted in a live boot. Then,

1. Just create `/` and `/home` (and any others you want) partitions on SSD #2.
2. Copy the the partitions over to new SSD

   - In case you want to update/reinstall linux, don't copy `/` partition, and only the `/home` partition. Then install Linux using live boot and CHOOSE you `/home` partition in `Something Else` option (DON'T check format)
   - Refer to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179437/how-to-install-new-version-of-ubuntu-and-keep-home-partition-untouched)
3. I would suggest not to copy the `/boot` partition, cause that will be done by `update-grub` command on new system. In your case, only copy `/` and `/home` (I guess `/swap` is not needed to be "copied")
4. Remove the SSD #1 Now
5. Now your Linux data copied over, I guess (from what I have experienced up until now) you need to `chroot` into the copied linux on `SSD #2`, and then run an `sudo update-grub`, and confirm that both `Windows` and your `Linux` are detected and added to grub on your new system. (This action will add entry for Linux into the `/dev/nvme0n1p1`)
6. Now if you reboot, you should be greeted by GRUB boot menu, with options for both Windows and Linux, and the Linux should have your data.

BUT I would suggest to research, and wait for comments by experts on my answer before proceeding with anything you don't know

Thanks

Comment: About point 3. But I should still create an empty boot partition on SSD #1 and select it during the `update-grub`, right?

Comment: what is the best command to copy `/` and `/home` partitions?

Comment: What exactly `chroot` command did you use?

Comment: To copy `/` and `/home` partitions (and especially for `/`) it is necessary to preserve all permissions, symbolic and hard links, special entries for devices etc. - otherwise you will just destroy the copied system and it will not work. I would suggest as a best method packing the entire filesystem to a `.tar` file and unpack it to the target filesystem.

Comment: Also, probably in step 5 you will have to do more than just `update-grub`. Most probably, you would also need to adjust the `/etc/fstab` file to your new partitions, so that they will be properly mounted on system boot. And maybe some other things, depending on the peculiarities of your system...

Comment: @ArtemDumanov, I didn't use a command to copy, if any. I just used gparted itself, just right click copy partition, right click paste partition, AFAIK

Comment: If you want a separate boot partition, then yes.
But In that case, you need to change the boot order in BIOS

Comment: `chroot` to change the root into you own Linux OS and execute commands in your Linux
Otherwise commands ran on Live Boot terminal will be executed on Live OS

But after researching, it seems like running `sudo update-grub` from live boot would work too

Comment: @raj raises some salient points that are missing from this rather vague answer.  Another crucial point is that you must not boot from "*SSD #1*", and then try to copy its root filesystem (which is only vaguely inferred by "*I assume you have used gparted in a live boot*" which may not be true).

Comment: Sorry for the vague answer, but I did warn. Though a clean install (as stated by @sawdust in his comment on the question itself) would be the safest.
First copy over your `/home` partition only, then do a clean install, and select you `/home` partition during installation (follow the answer I linked in my answer) 

Now for retaining your installed applications and packages, copy the `/opt` directory, and all installed packages using [apt-clone](https://ubunlog.com/en/apt-clone-copia-seguridad-paquetes/). And all you settings are already on your `/home`

I guess that's it